# como usar pyserial na interação com modem pci

Tags: python

Estou tentado criar um programa que disque para determinados numeros telefonicos chame duas vezes e mude para o proximo numero.

Estou usando pyserial para comunicação  com o modem pci só que o programa ocupa a porta mas o modem não disca.

Entao eu instalei um emulador de porta serial para ver se o programa estava enviando a string certa para porta e pelo emulador a string está sendo enviada mas o modem não executa.

se alguem poder me ajudar eu agradeço.Eu tambem testei a string no hypertermial funcionou normalmente

segue o codigo :

```
import serial
import time

#leitura da lista de tp
#Arquivo de leitura deve estar no mesmo diretorio do programa
porta ='COM3'
vel =115200
bytesize=8



arq = open("TP.txt",'r')
resul=arq.readlines()
arq.close()
ddd=input('Digite codigo DDD')
for i in range(len(resul)):
    resul[i].format(resul[0:8])
    tel=('ATDT'+ddd+resul[i]).rstrip('\t\n')
    print(tel)           
    if(i>=0):
        print('Enviando numero '+tel)
        try:
            con = serial.Serial(porta,vel,bytesize,parity='N',stopbits=1,timeout=1)
            con.write(tel.encode('utf-8'))
            time.sleep(1.8)
            con.close()
        except serial.SerialException:
             print("ERRO: Verifique se ha algum dispositivo conectado na porta!")
```